# Got "IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'laion400m-meta" Error when I tried to download laion-400m dataset

Tags: python, computer-vision, dataset

I tried to download the laion-400m dataset. I followed the instructions on GitHub to download the dataset. The first thing I did was download the metadata files. However, when I tried to download the datasets using this instruction

```
img2dataset --url_list laion400m-meta --input_format "parquet"\
         --url_col "URL" --caption_col "TEXT" --output_format webdataset\
           --output_folder laion400m-data --processes_count 16 --thread_count 128 --image_size 256\
             --save_additional_columns '["NSFW","similarity","LICENSE"]' --enable_wandb True
```

I got this error

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'laion400m-meta'
```

Comment: `--url_list laion400m-meta` That argument is supposed to be a _file_ containing a list of urls.  But you passed it a _directory_ instead.

Comment: In the GitHub Page, it is said that "url_list A file with the list of url of images to download. It can be a folder of such files. (required)"?

Comment: Ah, I missed that detail.  I see that those examples use the format `--url_list=dirname`, not as you have done `--url_list dirname`.  Try using that format.

Comment: I appreciate your help. After I uninstall and reinstall img2dataset package, the problem is resolved.